# Lookup tables best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, design-patterns

In my DB I have many lookups , which will have a UI for changing , I have MVC web site , and want to have those lookup loaded once , and refreshed if any changes happened

my data access layer looks like :

```
private ClassessEntities Context;
protected Repository()
{
    Context = new ArabicEWorldEntities();
}
public IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
}
public T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
}
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    return Context.CreateObjectSet<T>().ToList();
}
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllOrderBy(Func<T, object> keySelector)
{
    return Context.CreateObjectSet<T>().OrderBy(keySelector).ToList();
}
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllOrderByDescending(Func<T, object> keySelector)
{
    return Context.CreateObjectSet<T>().OrderByDescending(keySelector).ToList();
}
public void Commit()
{
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
public void Add(T entity)
{
    Context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AddObject(entity);
}
public void Update(T entity)
{
    Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
public void Delete(T entity)
{
    Context.DeleteObject(entity);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
public void Dispose()
{
    if (Context != null)
    {
        Context.Dispose();
    }
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

and to get the list from lookup I use method like

```
private static ClassesEntities Context;

public static IEnumerable<T> GetLookup<T>() where T : System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject
{
    try
    {
        var key = typeof(T).Name;
        // 1. we need the container for the conceptual model
        var container = Context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(
            Context.DefaultContainerName, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace);
        // 2. we need the name given to the element set in that conceptual model
        var name = container.BaseEntitySets.Where((s) => s.ElementType.Name.Equals(key)).FirstOrDefault().Name;
        // 3. finally, we can create a basic query for this set
        var query = Context.CreateQuery<T>("[" + name + "]");

        return query.ToList();
    }
    catch (System.Data.EntityException ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Entity Type supplied for Lookup", ex);
    }
}
```

any idea to handle the situation I discussed above to load them once and if any change reload them I call those method to my MVC using web service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a CachedLookup class that has an IEnumerable field for each type (or even a `Dictionary<Type,IEnumerable<T>>`) that contains the cached result and then GetLookup would be a non static method of that class. It would return the field if no changes have happened.

How you want the cache to be invalidated will depend. If you want the lookup to be updated in a reasonable time (ie not immediately) you could have a last updated time and then just check the current time (on GetLookup call) if it is lets say 30min after the last date and refresh the cache. If you want it to be immediate and there is some action within you application that invalidates the cache you could have a `InvalidateCache<T>()` method that refreshes that specific cache.

The CachedLookup will know how to refresh the cache and will just be a proxy to fetch the Lookups